# How to correctly set state in a loop in react functional component using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, react-hooks

Consider I'm uploading a bunch of files and I'm trying to keep track of the ones in progress so that whenever an upload is finished, I decrement my state until all are finished and finally I change my uploading state to `false`:
 (Here I made a `sleep` function to mimic the uploading process).

```js
import React, { useState} from "react";

const sleep = (ms, dev =1 ) => {
  const msWithDev = (Math.random() * dev + 1) * ms
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, msWithDev))
}

function Counter() {
  const [, setSortEnabled] = useState(true)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  const upload = async () => {
    await sleep(1000)
    setCount(c => c - 1)

      console.log(`count state: ${count}`)

      if (count === 0) {
        console.warn('Sort set to enabled again.')
        setSortEnabled(true)
    }
  }


  const onClick = ()  => {
    console.warn('Sort set to disabled.')
      arr.forEach(item => {
        setCount(c => c + 1)
        console.error(count)
        upload()
      })
    }

  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

The problem is in `upload`,

```
function `console.log(\`count state: ${count}\`)`
```

always logs `0` which means the state has never been updated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which means the state has never been updated

**It does get updated**, you are just logging **staled value** [because of closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#:~:text=A%20closure%20is%20the%20combination,scope%20from%20an%20inner%20function.).

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function.

To fix it, use `setState` [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

```
const onClick = () => {
  console.warn("Sort set to disabled.");
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    setCount((c) => {
      console.error(c);
      return c + 1;
    });
    upload();
  });
};
```

[image: Edit spring-sky-sw8gv]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on count, you must use `Promise.all` to wait for all files to be uploaded. In your case count is received from closure so even if the state is updated, the count variable remains unaffected.

You can implement the above logic with Promise.all like

```
function Counter() {
  const [, setSortEnabled] = useState(true)
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  const upload = async () => {
    await sleep(1000);
  }


  const onClick = async ()  => {
    console.warn('Sort set to disabled.')
      const promises = arr.map(item => {
        console.error(count)
        return upload()
      });
      await Promise.all(promises);
      console.warn('Sort set to enabled again.')
      setSortEnabled(true)
    }

  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

UPDATE:

To get around the closure issue of count state, you can make use of refs and useEffect. However its a workaround and should not be preferred

```
import React, { useState} from "react";

const sleep = (ms, dev =1 ) => {
  const msWithDev = (Math.random() * dev + 1) * ms
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, msWithDev))
}

function Counter() {
  const [, setSortEnabled] = useState(true)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  const countRef = useRef(count);
  useEffect(() => {
     countRef.current = count;
  }, [count ]);
  const upload = async () => {
    await sleep(1000)
    setCount(c => c - 1)

      console.log(`count state: ${count}`)

      if (countRef.current === 0) {
        console.warn('Sort set to enabled again.')
        setSortEnabled(true)
    }
  }


  const onClick = ()  => {
    console.warn('Sort set to disabled.')
      arr.forEach(item => {
        setCount(c => c + 1)
        upload();
      })
    }

  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham. Yeah I know about this approach but I preferred to have an explanation on how to properly set state in a loop not to get the staled values.

Comment: @MohsenTaleb that would lead to a hack since you would then need to store state in refs as the state values are bound by closure. I would prefer a cleaner way to write the code instead. Promise.all provides you that alternative

Comment: Anyways, I updated my post with an alternative solution

Comment: Agreed that promise.all is the cleanest way to do this. Using refs is less readable and also agreed, should not be preferred. But thanks for the update.

Comment: Already did with the first answer which was more related to my specific question and explained how I got the staled value in closure. sorry.

Comment: Sure, although from your question it didn't like you wanted an explantion but a way to make it work